# Adding Entity Framework core migration without using other projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

When I create ORM model project with Entity Framework Core, I encounter problem with migrations. I usually start my project with data layer then generate my data model. After that I add migration independently (from other projects). How can I do add first migration using commands only, without configuring migration on other project or making it an executable project (like console)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're trying to do but here are the DotNET EF Core commands to create migrations and database.

### Command

First command is to install the EF Core migration tools.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.0
```

The Second command can be used to create a migration.

```
dotnet-ef migrations add First --project YourProject
```

The third one to create the database in SQL Server. The database will be created in the SQL server instance which is specified in the connection string inside appsettings.json.

```
dotnet-ef database update --project YourProject
```

### Using a Separate Migrations Project

You may want to store your migrations in a different project than the one containing your DbContext. Then follow these MS Docs guidelines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: Actually, I don't want to that this way, because it needs a startup project that I want to avoid.

Comment: I want add migration independently from other projects and I don't want make my project executable.

Comment: Do you want migrations in a separate project?

Comment: If you want to run migrations. Ef core requires dbContext and some startup services to inject into the startup class. Otherwise, I think it's not possible.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think requirement of this is a startup project

Comment: In general way, it is true. But I want to make a library project and I don't want convert library to console.